# py2exe SSLError in making exe file for windows7

Tags: python, ssl, py2exe, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make an exe file with -py2exe Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv



def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

url = 'https://loadtv.info/'


html=get_html(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
article = soup.findAll('p')

text=[]
article_text = ''
for element in article:

 text.append(element.getText().encode('utf8'))



pages=soup.findAll('a',class_='more-link')
links=[]
for page in pages :

      links.append(page.get('href'))

zo=[]
for i in links:
 z=get_html(i)
 soup=BeautifulSoup(z, 'html.parser')
 t=[]
 r=soup.findAll('p')

 w=[]
 tex=[]
 for i in r :
    w.append(i.getText().encode('utf8')) 
 for i in range(3,6):
    tex.append(w[i])
 zo.append(tex)

video=[]
for i in links:
 z=get_html(i)
 soup=BeautifulSoup(z, 'html.parser')

 vid = soup.find("iframe").get('src')
 video.append(vid)





da={'links': links,'text' :zo,'video':video}
with open('C:\\2\\123.txt','wb') as f:

  writer=csv.writer(f)
  for i in da:
   for rows in da[i]:
    writer.writerow([rows])
```

I get the following error in log file after compilation:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "films.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "films.py", line 9, in resource_path
NameError: global name 'os' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "films.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "films.py", line 9, in get_html
  File "requests\api.pyc", line 70, in get
  File "requests\api.pyc", line 56, in request
  File "requests\sessions.pyc", line 488, in request
  File "requests\sessions.pyc", line 609, in send
  File "requests\adapters.pyc", line 497, in send
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I made exe by run in cmd  `python setup.py py2exe`

I have no idea how to fix it. The problem is related to SSL certificate, but I have added it to my setup modules. Please help.

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe


setup(
    windows=[{"script":"films.py"}],
    options={"py2exe": {"includes":["bs4","requests","csv"]}},
    zipfile=None

)
```

Comment: Seems that you are using the module os without importing it somewhere in films.py. Try to import os in this file.